# How can I put pictures next to each other and how can I add a location?

Tags: images

how can I put two pictures in one post next to each other?
And how can I add a date and location by the title of a post? [image]

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has some image classes built in and expects all themes to implement them for proper functionality. See [styling images documentation in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Images_in_Posts_and_Pages). Though for more elaborate cases you might need to us inline style or create a child theme with more elaborate CSS.

Date would likely be a matter of adding respective template tag in a theme's template.

Location would be more tricky, since you don't specify if you have the data implemented/captured already in some form.

Overall much of these (date aside) is open to wildly different implementations, in range from completely custom to use of existing helpers and frameworks.

Answer (score -2):

```
<img style="width:100%;height:10px;margin-bottom:20px;" src="image 1 link">

<img style="width:100%;height:10px;margin-bottom:20px;" src="image 2 link">
```

use the above code where you need the images to show,
you should change the values to ensure the image is place and positioned properly